# Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialised using a configuration object that does not match the API schema?

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

[image]

this is my webpack.config.js:

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    entry: './src/App.jsx',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        publicPath: '/dist/',
        filename: 'js/app.js'
    },
    resovle: {
        alias: {
            page: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/page')
        }
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.jsx$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    options: {
                        presets: ['env', 'react']
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                    fallback: "style-loader",
                    use: "css-loader"
                })
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                    fallback: 'style-loader',
                    use: ['css-loader', 'sass-loader']
                })
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpg|gif)$/,
                use: [
                    {
                      loader: 'url-loader',
                      options: {
                          limit: 8192,
                          name: 'resource/[name].[ext]'
                      }
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(woff|woff2|eot|ttf|otf|svg)$/,
                use: [
                    {
                      loader: 'url-loader',
                      options: {
                          limit: 8192,
                          name: 'resource/[name].[ext]'
                      }
                    }
                ]
            }  
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: './src/index.html'
        }),
        new ExtractTextPlugin('css/[name].css'),
    //公共模块
        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
            name: 'common',
            filename: 'js/base.js'
        })
    ],
    devServer: {
        port: 8081
    }
  };
```

i'm use webpack@3.10.0, webpack-dev-server@2.9.7, when i "npm run dev" get this error.

Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialised using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.
 - configuration has an unknown property 'resovle'. These properties are valid:
   object { amd?, bail?, cache?, context?, dependencies?, devServer?, devtool?, entry, externals?, loader?, module?, name?, node?, output?, parallelism?, performance?, plugins?, profile?, recordsInputPath?, recordsOutputPath?, recordsPath?, resolve?, resolveLoader?, stats?, target?, watch?, watchOptions? }
   For typos: please correct them.
   For loader options: webpack 2 no longer allows custom properties in configuration.
     Loaders should be updated to allow passing options via loader options in module.rules.
     Until loaders are updated one can use the LoaderOptionsPlugin to pass these options to the loader:
     plugins: [
       new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
         // test: /.xxx$/, // may apply this only for some modules
         options: {
           resovle: ...
         }
       })
     ]
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! backend@1.0.0 dev: `webpack-dev-server --open`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the backend@1.0.0 dev script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2018-03-21T09_48_18_093Z-debug.log

how to change webpack.config.js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is misspelling in your Webpack config. Check it the word `resovle` and change it to `resolve`.

```
resolve {
    alias: {
        page: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/page')
    }
}
```

The message error tells you what's wrong:
`Webpack has been initialised using a configuration object that does not match the API schema. - configuration has an unknown property 'resovle'`